# The limit of part of a function, given the limit of the whole function

Tags: limits

The question is:

> Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{f(x)-7}{x-1}=4$, find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)$.

The obvious answer is $7$, by going:
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{f(x)-7}{x-1}&=4\\
\Rightarrow\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}[f(x)-7]&=4\times{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}[x-1]}\\
\Rightarrow\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}[f(x)-7]&=0\\
\Rightarrow\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)&=7
\end{align*}$$
But this feels wrong. Specifically, the step of taking "${\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}[x-1]}$" over to the right hand side seems illegal. I justify this to myself by saying we can treat it like a number not equal to zero because it is a limit. But I don't believe my justification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anwser to yout "seems illegal" doubt: as
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-7}{x-1}\text{ exists}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 1}(x-1)\text{ exists},$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}(f(x)-7) = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-7}{x-1}\times\lim_{x\to 1}(x-1) = \cdots\text{ exists.}$$

Comment: Oh! Of course! Silly me for not writing all my working! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Its a matter of rewrite $f(x) = (x-1)\cdot \dfrac{f(x)-7}{x-1} + 7\Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{x\to1}(x-1)\cdot \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{f(x)-7}{x-1} + \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} 7 = ?$

Comment: So $7$ is correct then?

Comment: Yes. But I am confused because I give the answer as $7$ in my question, so am wondering why you didn't just say "Yes, the answer is $7$. Another way to see this is by..." or "Yes, the answer is $7$. Your way is incorrect because... A better way to get the answer is by...". So I am wondering if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The subtlety of this question is where the 4 comes from, since $f(1)$ must be 7 for the limit to exist.  This quotient is the definition of *derivitive* so what it's saying is that $f'(1) = 4.$